# Tensorflow 1.14+: docker image doesn't work as expected with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to test my setup using docker and tensorflow. I am using the official Tensorflow image [tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/latest-gpu-py3-jupyter/images/sha256-613cdca993785f7c41c744942871fc5358bc0110f6f5cb5b00a4b459356d55e4)

My project has the minimum structure:

```
project/
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    jupyter/
        README.md
```

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
# from official image
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter
# add my notebooks so they are a part of the container
ADD ./jupyter /tf/notebooks


# copy-paste from tf github dockerfile in attempt to troubleshoot
# https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu-jupyter.Dockerfile
WORKDIR /tf
RUN which jupyter
CMD ["jupyter-notebook --notebook-dir=/tf/notebooks --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root"]
```

and the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  tf:
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter

    # mount host system volume to save updates from container
    volumes:
      - jupyter:/tf/notebooks

    ports:
      - '8888:8888'

    # added as part of troubleshooting
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile


volumes:
  jupyter:
```

running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` succeeds (if the `CMD` in the `Dockerfile` is commented out), but just exits. From the [docker hub repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow), I thought adding the volume would auto-start a notebook.

Trying to run `jupyter-notebook` or `jupyter notebook` fails.

Thoughts on how to correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a custom image from the official one adding the notebook directory then the image property in the docker-compose should be the name of the your local image not the tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter. All you need is in this case a following Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter
ADD ./jupyter /tf/notebooks
```

In this case the docker-compose.yaml file should look like the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  tf:
    image: tensorflow

    # mount host system volume to save updates from container
    volumes:
      - jupyter:/tf/notebooks

    ports:
      - '8888:8888'

    # added as part of troubleshooting
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile


volumes:
  jupyter:
```

Note, that the image is tensorflow.

However, there is really no need to use the custom Dockerfile. Just use the following docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  tf:
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter

    # mount host system volume to save updates from container
    volumes:
      - ./jupyter:/tf/notebooks:Z

    ports:
      - '8888:8888'
```

It will directly map your local jupyter directory to the container and will use an official image without modification.

Note though, it might not work as expected on Windows due to issues with mapping of the host directories.

Comment: the build was added as part of troubleshooting, implying I also tried it without. What you currently have results in `ERROR: for tf  Cannot start service tf: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"jupyter notebook --notebook- ...`

Comment: I suspect that you have your own broken copy that was build using the above Dockerfile under the name 'tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter' locally.

Run the `docker image rm tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter` first and pull the fresh tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.0rc2-gpu-py3-jupyter image from the docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RUN pip3 install nvidia-tensorflow
```

this will install tf 1.15